# Scrollheight not get height on dynamic content render thorugh ajax and failed to initate Slimscroll from bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, slimscroll

I spent much time to take scrollheight properly but all actions gone failed.

**Problem:**
1- Facing Problem to retrieve scrollheight on dynamic content render

2- slimscroll not start from bottom.

**Dynamic content load timely so I use scrollheight with slimscroll**

3- Slimscroll position start from bottom affect due to scrollheight.

I integrate slimscroll with a chat system container, while content retrieve from ajax and insert (apppend) to chat area.
**I take scrollheight of that container**. so I can initiate scroll (slimscroll plugin) from bottom,

**but found two problems here**

1- slimscroll not start from bottom on dynamic content.

2- scrollheight return zero right after content render.

```
$.ajax({ // retrieve data request }).done(function (result) {
$.each(data, function (index, value) { // markup concatenation done })
$(html).insertBefore('.message-center .chat-list .typing-status');
```

**Then I initiate slimscroll code to do action according to scrollheight**

```
var chatList = $('.message-center .chat-list');

    var scrollTo_int = chatList.prop('scrollHeight') + 'px';

    $('.chat-list').slimScroll({
        scrollTo : scrollTo_int,
        height: '400',
        start: 'bottom',
        alwaysVisible: true
    });
```

But scrollheight shows me zero but If I wait for 2 seconds and put this code in settimeout 
same slimscroll initialization code in settimeout

```
// setTimeout(function () {
                //     chatToBottom();
                // }, 2000);
```

**ScrollHeight return correct height and also slimscroll work perfectly**. I don't want to wait for these two seconds.

**Why I'm failed to get scrollheight even content has been rendered,**

**If any one can suggest me a good way like:**

1- A callback method wait until scrollheight > 0 then function must be initiate.

2- I want to prevent settimeout function, I thought If content increase it may take 1 or 2 second more. that's my thinking.

I spent much time but failed to tackle this, Your suggestion may help to me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**Scrollheight return height correctly** and slimscroll also show scroll from bottom **If I open popup immediately** after page load complete or **set popup visibility hidden instead of display none.**.

**My Test case:**

During more time to focus on scrollheight and slimscroll, I noticed there's a problem with popup which is hidden where chat rendered.

1- **When I display chat in body content area** so scroll start from bottom, 
and also scrollheight return height greater than zero.

**When I show chat in popup:**

2- If I immediately open chat popup then **point-3 case failed** and chat shown correctly and scroll height also return **greater than zero**

3- It chat popup not open immediately so chat area display scrollheight zero and also slimscroll start from top.

Now I have to put logic that If **user open popup so show chat from bottom**
and also If user hide the popup in between chat start from there where user stop.

Anyhow thanks who see this question, Now I work on other scenarios.